# Bigquery Column addition and historical update

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We have a bigquery table which holds around 50 GB of logistics data. Recently due to business requirement we had to introduce a new column which works pretty well for the new data but we want to fix the historical data as well for this column.

This personal column is pushed from python and is derived from logistics column which is pipe delimited.

[image: Sample Table]

Note :We have data till 2021-01-01 which needs to be updated.

What is the fastest way to achieve this using SQL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding, Personal is actually derived from Y or N substring in `logistics`. If thats so, then you can fetch this substring using regex and later you could populate `Personal` based on this. As your table is in BigQuery so you can execute following command to do the same.[Kindly change regex as per your requirement]

```
e.g.  UPDATE `project.dataset.table_name`
      SET Personal = CASE 
                      WHEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(Logistics, r'\|[YN]\|') = '|Y|'
                      THEN 'Yes'
                      ELSE 'No'
                     END
      WHERE DATE <= DATE('2021-01-01')
```

Comment: Thanks. This should be able to do the required. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use an `update` query to calculate the `Logistics` columns for historical data :

```sql
update `my_project.my_dataset.my_table`
set Logistics = CONCAT(column1, "|", column2, "|", ....)
where 1 = 1
```

If your table is partitioned (maybe the column `Date`), you can add dates ranges in `where` clause if needed to not process all the table.

For example if historical data is until a date, you are not obliged to execute the `update` query for all the data in table, and in this case the cost will be cheaper.